# Dual monitor with different resolutions problem

Tags: 12.04, monitor

I'm on an LG R405 with a PM965 chipset and a NVIDIA GeForce Go 8400M GS gaphics card.
I'm trying to use an external monitor (Benq senseye3 G2222HDL) through a VGA out port.
All was fine when installing except for the screen layouts were flip-flopped (computer defalut setup so external monitor was to the right instead of left).
When I moved the secondary monitor to its real position in the setup, I started getting strange problems.
I loose representation of large portions of the screen, on both screens, and have to reboot.
If I plug the monitor in after rebooting I get more problems than when booting up with the monitor already plugged in, but in both cases I can barely see what I'm doing.

Please advice!

Regards
/M

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have two displays or use the external as your primary monitor?

I think when two monitors are plugged in and they share the desktop (duplicate display) it will limit the display to the smallest resolution. try splitting the displays then adjusting the resolution of your external to what you need. and make sure you boot with it already plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows Laptop try pressing "windows (super key) + P" then select duplicate.
the same display will be on both the monitors and if you are trying to make it as extended monitor you can choose the option in "Windows + P" list.
Moreover, put the resolution to the lower like 800 X 600. 
should be alright.
cheers
Vik